# How to exclude a control from ASP.NET validation when hidden (display:none;)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex, validation

**HOW TO EXCLUDE A CONTROL FROM ASP.NET VALIDATION WHEN HIDDEN?**

- A checkbox is used to alternate between two textboxs.
- Either one or the other is required **NOT BOTH**.
- I want the required field to disabled when hidden.

I am aware `enabled="false"` and `visible="false"` create this behaviour however I want to maintain the jquery fade in out animation.

I tried to add disabled false property to javascript but couldn't get it to work.
Other solutions found online don't seem to achieve what is needed.

**ASP.NET**

```
<div class="Hide1">
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="Server"/>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" RunAt="Server" ControlToValidate="tb"/>
</div>

<div class="Hide2">
  <asp:TextBox ID="tb2" runat="Server"/>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv2" RunAt="Server" ControlToValidate="tb2"/>
</div>

<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="Server" Text="GO"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  $('.tb').hide();
  $('#CB').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.tb2').fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('.tb').fadeIn();
      });
    } else {
      $('.tb').fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('.tb2').fadeIn();
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: I vaguely remember doing this in the past, but I needed some server-side code to achieve it. Something like ignoring the field when validating the form.

Comment: I think you must use a custom validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=CB.ClientID%>').checked) {
   ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rfv1.ClientID %>'), true);
   ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rfv2.ClientID %>'), false);
   $('.tb2').fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('.tb').fadeIn();
      });
 }
 else {
       ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rfv1.ClientID %>'), false);
       ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= rfv2.ClientID %>'), true);
       $('.tb').fadeOut(100, function () {
          $('.tb2').fadeIn();
          });
      }
```

**Note:** rfv1 and rfv2 are the id's of the two required validators and please avoid giving same id to validators.

**Update**

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=CB.ClientID%>').checked) {
       ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%= rfv1.ClientID %>"), true);
       ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%= rfv2.ClientID %>"), false);
       $('.tb2').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $('.tb').fadeIn();
          });
     }
     else {
           ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%= rfv1.ClientID %>"), false);
           ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("#<%= rfv2.ClientID %>"), true);
           $('.tb').fadeOut(100, function () {
              $('.tb2').fadeIn();
              });
          }
```

Comment: This is the type of solution I am looking for but cant get it working.

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: It appears ValidatorEnable doesnt support jquery. I need to use getElementsByClass as I have many validators on page not just two and using ID's would create to much code.

Comment: yeah validator enable doesn't support jquery.. :(

finding an alternative solution to it.

Comment: I thought it would be as simple as adding enabled or visible false to controls with jquery would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54786/discussion-between-sid-m-and-obsidion).

Answer (score 1):

Just set the property "CauseValidation" of the control to "False".
For example

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

And this has to be accomplished in server side code.

Hope this helps.

**Edit 1**

If it has to be done in javascrpt .. I think the visibility of the control should be checked in validation

```
function validate()
{
 if control is hidden
 { avoid validation
 }
 else
 {validate
 }
}
```

Comment: This condition needs to be alternated when javascript is triggered so executing server side code would not work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this. It does need to be javascript and your suggestion is what I am trying to implement but with little success.

Comment: what is blocking now?

Answer (score 1):

To disable a required field validator

```
 document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator1').enabled=false;
```

To enable a required field validator

```
 document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator1').enabled=true;
```